# Is texture 1D array a valid way to handle object coloring?

Tags: opengl, textures

I would like to render game UI, and for that I need rectangles. However, since a button could be textured just as well as solid color or (multistop)gradient a problem arises. I would also like all types of rectangles(buttons) somehow at least partially uniform at handling.
I have been puzzled by this issue for quite a time and idea came across my mind - what if I stored colors to a 1D texture array and treat all rectangles as textured. Could you give me some example how to do this? Or event better a reason not-to solve it this way and point to better solution?

Comment: Why not just use a vertex attribute?

Comment: Vertex attribute would require unnecessary data(each vertex would have to get both color and UV) and either additional math or condition jump. Remember - rectangle can have either texture or color.

Comment: You don't need condition jump, a invalid texture (texture index 0) is always 100% white. This seems to be a very premature optimization to me.

Comment: +1, I didnt know that about 0 texture. However, this is not much about optimization but the goal was to have a rectangle that can be processed exactly same way regardless background type as background is irrelevant for other (GUI) logic.

Comment: @API-Beast i'm afraid that's not always true: on my gpu/implementation/whatever, a 0 texture acts as if it's filled with zeroes (which would be black and 100% transparent as RGBA). this also makes for interesting effects if used with compositing window managers (I can actually render holes into the window)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

- Create a texture holding all the colors you want.
- For the actual button geometry, set the texture coordinates to the appropriate region of the color texture (they can all be the same value, in fact).

Comment: And what if I dont know in advance how many colors(and which) do I need? Is better to use 1d array, rectangle texture or just classic 2d texture?

Comment: Doesn't matter, really; in all cases you'd need to add the new texels to the texture.